# casper fail to pass args to fill methos

Tags: casperjs

```
 keyword = 'Hotels';

casper.thenOpen('domain.com', function() {
  // search for ...
    this.fill('form[action="/query"]', { q: 'pizza' }, true);
 });
```

Here how to pass 'keyword' variable instead of 'pizza' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `{ q: keyword }`?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get "no form field matching names selector "q" in form".